# Explain the necessity of database drivers, libraries, dlls in a python application that interacts with a remote database?

Tags: python, sql, database, oracle, database-connection

I have written a python script that connects to a remote Oracle database and inserts some data into its tables.

In the process I had to first import cx_Oracle package and install Oracle InstantClient on my local computer for the script to execute properly.

What I don't understand is why did I have to install InstantClient?
I tried to read through the docs but I believe I am missing some fundamental understanding of how databases work and communicate.

Why do I need all the external drivers, dlls, libraries for a python script to be able to communicate with a remote db? I believe this makes packaging and distribution of a python executable much harder.
Also what is InstantClient anyway?
Is it a driver? What is a driver? Is it simply a collection of "programs" that know how to communicate with Oracle databases? If so, why couldn't that be accomplished with a simple import of a python package?

This may sound like I did not do my own research beforehand, but I'm sorry, I tried, and like I said, I believe I am missing some underlying fundamental knowledge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have a collection of drivers that allow you to communicate with an Oracle Database. Most of these are 'wrappers' of a sort that piggyback on the Oracle Client. Compiled C binaries that use something we call 'Oracle Net' (not to be confused with .NET) to work with Oracle.

So our python, php, perl, odbc, etc drivers are small programs written such that they can be used to take advantage of the Oracle Client on your system.

The Oracle Client is much more than a driver. It can include user interfaces such as SQL*Plus, SQL*Loader, etc. Or it can be JUST a set of drivers - it depends on which exact package you choose to download and install. And speaking of 'install' - if you grab the Instant Client, there's nothing to install. You just unzip it and update your environment path bits appropriately so the drivers can be loaded.

Comment: @thatjeffsmitth Thanks for the answer. Does this mean that  I should include the InstantClient with the python script everywhere I want to use said python script? Because InstantClient itself is quite a large directory, roughly 90Mb. Or could I strip it down further, to only include the absolute neccesary files?

Comment: "To use cx_Oracle 7 with Python and Oracle Database you need:

Oracle client libraries. These can be from the free Oracle Instant Client, or those included in Oracle Database if Python is on the same machine as the database. "

So, yes.

Comment: The way I think about it is that the "Oracle Client" needed by cx_Oracle is the Oracle Call Interface (OCI) libraries. These libraries know the Oracle network protocol to connect to Oracle DB. They do encryption, caching, provide high availability, etc etc.   To connect anything to Oracle DB you have to use JDBC "Thin", .NET managed, or you can use an OCI-based API (JDBC "Thick", .NET unmanaged, or any OCI-based driver like cx_Oracle, godror, node-oracledb, etc etc). Bottom line: something has to be installed that can talk the network protocol.

Comment: There is an architecture diagram at https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/introduction.html#architecture

Comment: @ChristopherJones Thanks, very useful. I kind of understand the why, but now I wonder if it's possible to package everything needed (the OCI libraries and the whole python program) into one simple .exe file. Perhaps this doesn't belong here anymore and should be discussed elsewhere.

Comment: Yes, but the solution varies by platform. On Windows just put the Instant Client DLLs in the same directory as the cx_Oracle library. This works because cx_Oracle uses [this code to load the Oracle client libraries](https://github.com/oracle/odpi/blob/v3.3.0/src/dpiOci.c#L1726-L1731). On other platforms you will need a wrapper shell script that sets LD_LIBRARY_PATH to the location of the Instant Client libraries.